# Using .so of other python package

Tags: python, linux, python-netifaces

I what to take '[netifaces](https://github.com/raphdg/netifaces)' python package and load `netifaces.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` with `cython.cdll.LoadLibrary`. But I get error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 360, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /home/urosjarc/vcs-ss/sc7-admingui-scripts/htbin/netifaces.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: AF_INET
```

Does 1one knows how to resolve it?

```
▶ ldd netifaces.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd01b72000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f264709c000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2646cd5000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556b41e44000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the netifaces package working for you? The error sounds like some missing dependencies. If it is working, then have a look how they load it. Then thet probably load another library as well, which contains the missing symbols.